# DStream JSON object to SQLite

Tags: json, sqlite, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

stack overflow community,

I have the following question:

I am using Spark Streaming and KafkaUtils to read from a Kafka topic, then I transform the Dstream to JSON. What I want is to save this JSON object to an SQLite database with a column-row format.

Sample of the code I run in spark-streaming:

```
import sys
import json
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

if __name__ == '__main__':

    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("PythonStreamingDirectKafka").setMaster("spark://spark-master:7077")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 20)
    brokers, topic = sys.argv[1:]
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {'metadata.broker.list': brokers})
    message = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
    message.pprint()

    # Functions
    json_object = message.map(lambda s: eval(s))
    temperatures_object = json_object.map(lambda s: s["temperature_value"])

    #Aggregations
    json_object.pprint()
    temperatures_object.pprint()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

The output of DStream

[DStream output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKdeQ.png)

SQLite schema:

[Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cccle.png)

Do you have any idea how to achieve this? It's complicated to me how to transfer JSON data to SQLite from spark streaming using Pyspark.

I appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: I don't think you can use sqlite with a distributed query... It would then write to individual sqlite files on each executor node

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you for the answer. What would you suggest to use instead? MongoDB or anything else...

Comment: Mongo, Cassandra, Hbase, mysql, Postgres, etc. Anything that accepts remote connections